# Testing an Application on  device in xcode 4

Tags: iphone

I am trying to test my iPhone app in XCode 4 and it is telling me that i don't have a valid provisioning profile even though i do. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of factors that could cause this.  More information is needed.  The primary things I would suggest are:

1. Is your device authorized in the provisioning profile (using the Developer Portal or team provisioning profile)
2. Have you downloaded the latest profile from the developer portal? And made sure its not expired?
3. Have you specified the correct provisioning profile in the build settings for your project? If you have had to make changes to the profile or renew it you will have to re-download it AND install it in Xcode AND change your build settings to point to the new one even though it has the same name.

Comment: Answers to question 1 and 2 are yes. Question 3 - Where are the build settings in xcode 4?